# Issue retrieving relative Altitude Information on Apple Watch 3

Tags: swift, apple-watch, altitude, cmaltimeter

I would like to log relative altitude changes on apple watch 3 using the CMAltimeter class. On simulator the isRelativeAltitudeAvailable() function returns false, so I tested on real device. Here I noticed, that information is provided, but by far too much alt meters (e.g. making 100-1000 m just by moving around on same level). What point I am missing?
- expecting that first point is 0
- following relativeAltitudes are changes relative to this in meters.
Thanks for you help!

Comment: I have placed the device on one surface still altitude change every second. Do you know why?

Comment: Actually no, maybe it's an accuracy issue of the barometer of your device? How big is the deviation you see?

Comment: in iWatch its around 0.5 -1 meter but in iPhone its huge.

Comment: after testing: relative Altimeter doesn't work reliable inside (no idea why, but that's also my experience). I removed my comment before: new relative altimeter value is alway reporting a relative change to the predecessor one (before I wrote to the initial value, what is wrong)

Comment: Sorry my last comment is not correct, I paste the apple API docu: For the first altitude event delivered to your altimeter object, the value of this property is 0. Subsequent events contain a number that reflects the relative change in altitude with respect to the first reported event. For example, if the altitude changed five meters between the first and second events, the value in this property is 5 for the second event.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `CLLocation` see [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation/1423820-altitude) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I do this in case of Apple Watch 1&2. For AW3 I would like to take the Barometer output, which should be more accurate than GPS derived altimeter data (specially when it comes to accumulate pos/neg altitude differences)